# Using AngularJS Library for Monitoring or Dashboard Pages

Tags: angularjs

I am planning to develop my monitoring/dashboard pages for hardware devices like Cisco router/switch/controller using Angular JS Library.

My page contains graphs(line & area), Google maps, tables and some blocks (div with value)

1. Is it feasible to use Angular for monitoring data?
2. What are the advantages we can get by using Angular? since it is only monitoring we don't have to use 2 way binding.

I am looking for few points to justify why we need angularJS for monitoring/dashboard kind of pages rather than JQuery/Javascript.

Please let me know your thoughts and comments.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you would want two way data binding for monitoring (at least in my mind...send request to check hardware, get response, assign to scope, auto updates dash)

Comment: Since it is not configuration i dont modify the json. i just populate it in div or pass it to the components(highchats,google maps).

Comment: I using angularjs for a week. All I can say is, its feasible, just I needed few days to accomplish very basic stuff properly in angular way.

Answer (score 12):

Using AngularJS is totally feasible.
Main advantages is that charts can be implemented as reusable components (AngularJS directives).

There is a project in development that allows building dashboard from arbitrary directives

Running Demo http://nickholub.github.io/angular-dashboard-app

Demo source code https://github.com/nickholub/angular-dashboard-app

Dashboard directive itself https://github.com/nickholub/angular-ui-dashboard

And here is example of visualizing data coming from WebSocket 
https://github.com/nickholub/angular-real-time-charts

Comment: Those were very useful links which i can showcase to others to prove angular will be a best fit for monitoring/dashboard kind of modules.  

Thanks! Webdev

Answer (score 1):

If your site is 100% static - and by that I mean that you do a request for a status page, and the page you get will never change before you do a new request - then angular might be a little unnecessary.

But if you want your status page to 'live', you could use socket.io to push new events and data to the client and let angular take care of the ui refresh.

There are some angular directives to work with graphs, but I have no experience using them.

Some pointers:

- Node.js + socket.io + angular.js:
  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/
- angular.js + charts:  http://ngmodules.org/tags/charts

Comment: Thanks Vegar! The monitoring is not a static page it auto refresh every min and a heart beat request will be sent to fetch current status.

Comment: If so, you could use angulars $http service to fetch the current status and let angular handle the gui update.

Comment: @Raghukumarachari If all clients poll every x seconds your server will overload. Let the server inform the clients via socket.io (push technology using html5 web sockets) or ASP.NET SignalR is you use .NET

Comment: @Pascal That is interesting. Can you point me to the code where it is done and can see it in live.

Comment: My answer already contains link to example on using socket.io and angular.js. Here is the [SignalR stockticker example](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR-StockTicker) implemented with angular if asp is your thing: http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.no/2013/05/ImplementingSignalRStockTickerUsingAngularJSPart1.html